# Adding Guidelines in Plot in Netlogo

Tags: plot, netlogo

I have a plot in Netlogo that shows the average heading of all turtles. Even when the scale is set from 0 to 360 it is a little hard to read, so I wanted to add horizontal guidelines at 90, 180, and 270. I can't find anything in the manual or web on how to do this. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `plotxy` to 'draw' well-enough for most purposes like this. For example, I've created a new plot and added this code to the "Plot update commands" field:

```
create-temporary-plot-pen "temp"
set-plot-pen-color 7 
foreach [ 90 180 270 ] [ h ->
plot-pen-up
plotxy 0 h
plot-pen-down
plotxy plot-x-max h
]
```

On each update (to maintain the lines as the scale of the x axis changes, in this example), this code iterates over the y values of interest, turns the pen off temporarily, moves the pen to x = 0 and y = h, then draws a horizontal line to whatever x is the current maximum x value for the plot. Output should look something like:

[image]